# Incrementar propriedade de um objeto dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Não sei qual é a melhor maneira de implementar isso, estou tentando com switch sem sucesso...
Ao clicar no botão, quero incrementar a propriedade "qtd";

```js
choice=[
  {"id":"1","name":"PRODUTO1","qtd":"0"},
  {"id":"2","name":"PRODUTO2","qtd":"0"},
  {"id":"3","name":"PRODUTO3","qtd":"0"},  
];

addQtd(id){
    switch(id){
      case '1':
      this.choice[0].qtd++;
      break;
      case '2':
      this.choice[1].qtd++;
      break;
      case '3':
      this.choice[2].qtd++;
      break;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of choice">
  <button (click)="addQtd(item.id)">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma e eliminar a função `addQtd`:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of choice">
  <button ion-button (click)="item.qtd = item.qtd + 1">Add</button>
  <p>{{item.qtd}}</p> <!-- so para mostrar na tela, pode retirar -->
</ion-item>
```

Outra coisa é que sua propriedade `qtd` está setado como string, você não iria conseguir incrementar somando um numero a uma string, caso essa quantidade venha de um servidor como string, não se esqueça de dar um parse pra number usando `Number(variavelQtd)`. Ficando então `{..., qtd: Number(variavelQtd)}`.

Mas caso você queira ter um controle pelo seu arquivo .ts pode fazer assim:

HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of choice; let i = index"> <!-- pega o index do item no ngFor -->
  <button ion-button (click)="addQtd(i)">Add</button>
</ion-item>
```

No seu .ts:

```
addQtd(index){
  this.choices[index].qtd = this.choices[index].qtd + 1;
}
```

Espero que te ajude :D